# Units for types in C++

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines

In the [C++ Core Guidlines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) P.1 `change_speed` example, it shows a `Speed` type that is used as shown below:

```
change_speed(Speed s); // better: the meaning of s is specified
// ...
change_speed(2.3); // error: no unit
change_speed(23m / 10s); // meters per second
```

I am particularly interested in the last two lines of this example.  The first seems to suggest that if you provide no units with the argument to `change_speed` it will throw an error.  The last line shows the units defined using some the `m` and `s` literals.  Are both of these new features in modern versions of C++?  If so, how would something like this be implemented, and what version of C++ is required?

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal)

Comment: Perhaps this is what you ment: It won't throw an error, It won't compile, because `change_speed` takes a Speed and not a floating point literal.

Comment: check out [Boost.Units](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/boost_units.html)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the example from the core guidelines uses user-defined literals to construct application-specific types that intuitively represent physical quantities. To illustrate them for the specific example, consider these types:

```
/* "Strong" speed type, unit is always [m/s]. */
struct Speed {
   long double value;
};

/* "Strong" length type, parameterized by a unit as multiples of [m]. */    
template <class Period = std::ratio<1>> struct Length {
   unsigned long long value;
};
```

It probably doesn't make much sense to track the unit of `Length` objects, but not for `Speed` instances, but let's consider the simplest possible example here. Now, let's look at two user-defined literals:

```
#include <ratio>

auto operator ""_m(unsigned long long n)
{
   return Length<>{n};
}

auto operator ""_km(unsigned long long n)
{
   return Length<std::kilo>{n};
}
```

They let you instantiate `Length` objects like this:

```
/* We use auto here, because the suffix is so crystal clear: */
const auto lengthInMeter = 23_m;
const auto lengthInKilometer = 23_km;
```

In order to cosntruct a `Speed` instance, let's define an appropriate operator for dividing a `Length` by a `duration`:

```
#include <chrono>

template <class LengthRatio, class Rep, class DurationRatio>
auto operator / (const Length<LengthRatio>& lhs,
      const std::chrono::duration<Rep, DurationRatio>& rhs)
{
   const auto lengthFactor = static_cast<double>(LengthRatio::num)/LengthRatio::den;
   const auto rhsInSeconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(rhs);

   return Speed{lengthFactor*lhs.value/rhsInSeconds.count()};
}
```

Now, let's look at the example from the core guidelines again,

```
void change_speed(const Speed& s)
{
    /* Complicated stuff... */
}
```

but most importantly, how you can call such a function:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int main(int, char **)
{
   change_speed(23_m/1s);
   change_speed(42_km/3600s);
   change_speed(42_km/1h);

   return 0;
}
```

As @KillzoneKid mentioned in the comments, C++11 is required for this to work.

Answer (score 4):

There are two different things involved in your code:

1. The use of strong/unit types to make your code more robust, i.e., you differentiate two integer types. This is built-in in some languages (e.g., Ada), but not in  C++, but you can create classes that wraps integer types to mimic such behavior (see below).
2. The use of operator literals to create instances of such classes in *user-friendly* way, i.e., you write `1s` instead of `seconds{1}`. This is simply a convenience feature, which can be useful in some places.

Using strong integer types is very useful because it makes your code much less error prone<sup>*</sup>:

- You cannot convert between types representing durations and lengths, as in real life.
- Within types representing the same kind of things (e.g., `seconds` and `hours`), there are not implicit conversions if you lose precision, e.g., you cannot convert `seconds` to `hours`, unless you are representing hours with floating point type (`float` / `double`).
- The (implicit and non-implicit) conversions takes care of the scaling for you: you can convert `hours` to `seconds` without having to manually multiply by 3600.
- You can provide realistic operators that will takes care of conversions for you, e.g., in your example, there is a division operator between lengths and durations that gives speeds. The exact type of speed is automatically deduced from the type of the length and the type of duration:

```
auto speed = 70_km / 1_h; // Don't bother deducing the type of speed, let the compiler do it for you.
```

- Unit types are **self-documented**: If a function returns `microseconds`, you know what this is, you do not have to hope that the guy documenting the function returning  `unsigned long long` mentioned that this represents microseconds...

<sub><sup>*</sup> I am only talking about implicit conversion here, of course, you can do conversion explicitly, e.g., using `duration_cast` (loss of precision).</sub>

---

**Unit types**

Wrapping integer types in "unit" classes has always been available, but C++11 brought one standard wrapped integer type: [`std::chrono::duration`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration).

A "unit" class can be defined by:

- the type of thing it represents: time, length, weight, speed, ...
- the C++ type it uses to represent these data: `int`, `double`, ...
- the ratio between this type and the "1-type" of the same unit.

Currently, only duration-like types are provided by the standard, but there have been discussion (maybe a proposal?) for providing a more generic basic unit type such as:

```
template <class Unit, class Rep, class Ratio = std::ratio<1>> class unit;
```

...where `Unit` would be a placeholder indicating the kind of thing represented, e.g.:

```
struct length_t { };

template <class Rep, class Ratio = std::ratio<1>>
using length = unit<length_t, Rep, Ratio>;
```

But this is not standard yet, so let's have a look at `std::chrono::duration`:

```
template <class Rep, class Period = std::ratio<1>> class duration;
```

The `Rep` template parameters is the C++ type:

- Standard defined durations types have integer representations (implementation defined).
- The underlying type defines the type of conversions that can be implicitly made:

  - You can convert integer hours to integer seconds implicitly (multiply by 3600).
  - You cannot convert integer seconds to integer hours implicitly because you would lose precision.
  - You can convert integer seconds to `double` hours.

The `Period` template parameters defines the ratio between the `duration` type and one second (which is the basic duration chosen):

- [`std::ratio`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) is a very convenient standard-defined type that simply represent a ratio between two integers, with corresponding operations (`*`, `/`, ...).
- The standad provides multiple duration types with various ratios: `std::chrono::seconds`, `std::chrono::minutes`, ...

---

**Operator literals**

These have been introduced in C++11 and are [literals operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal#Literal_operators).

The `s` one is standard and is included in the [`chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) standard library:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
auto one_second = 1s;
auto one_hour = 1h;
```

The `m` one is not standard, and thus should be prefixed by `_` (since it is user-defined), like `23_m`. You can define your own operator like so:

```
constexpr auto operator "" _m(unsigned long long ull) { 
    return meters{ull};
}
```

Comment: Once we will have units in C++ we will understand how good practice is to perform dimensional analysis and how computing simulation using dimensionless equation is such a good solution! ;)

Comment: @Oliv It's already quite easy to implements units in C++, especially if you simply wraps a `std::chrono::duration`. ;)

Comment: That lacks the concept of Dimension (the Units template parameter), and the possibility to multiply/divide numbers with different dimension: 1 meter / 1 second = 1 meter/second => dimensionaly meter/second = speed. See boost units.